# Creating a dictionary from a txt file with key year and values a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have the txt file  below

```
2014,STAR,105,234
2014,COMET,2877,1426
2014,ASTEROID,73,68
2014,PLANET,134,143
2014,"ACTIVE STARS,DEADSTARS",166,125
2015,STAR,69,24
2015,ASTEROID,59,32
2015,PLANET,42,13
2015,STAR,79,33
2015,BLACK HOLES,8,3
2015,"ACTIVE STARS,DEADSTARS",19,16
2015,ASTEROID,12,0
2016,STAR,120,47
2016,"ACTIVE STARS,DEADSTARS",4,1
2016,PLANET,14,12
2016,ASTEROID,21,1
```

and i need to write a function that reads the file and creates a dictionary with key the year, and values, a list with values the sum of 3 column and the sum of 4 column of txt file for the year.

```
def file_read(fname):
  with open(fname,'r') as document:
    
    zip_lists=[]
    dictionary1 ={}
    tempYear=[]
    tempSum3=[]
    tempSum4=[]
    for line in document:
        #print(line)
        line=line.strip()
        alist=line.split(',')
        tempYear.append(alist[0])
        #print(alist[2])
        if len(alist)==5:
          tempSum3.append(int(alist[3]))
          tempSum4.append(int(alist[4]))
          
        else:
          tempSum3.append(int(alist[2]))
          tempSum4.append(int(alist[3]))

    
    zip_lists=zip(tempSum3,tempSum4)
    

    dictionary1=dict(zip(tempYear,zip_lists))
   
    return dictionary1
```

Comment: What is the question? Example output (for what you are looking to create) always helps...

Comment: The question is to write a function who reads the file and create a dictionary with key the year, and values a list(i think a tuble) that has the sum of column 3 and the sum of column 4 for the year. The output of my code is `{'2014': (166, 125), '2015': (12, 0), '2016': (21, 1)}` but its wrong because in the first tuble (166,125) i need the sum of all the 3rd column of year 2014 and the sum of year 2014 of column 4rd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want. Maybe this work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

def file_read(fname):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=',')
    df.columns = ['Year', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

    sum_col3 = df.groupby('Year')['col3'].sum().to_list()
    sum_col4 = df.groupby('Year')['col4'].sum().to_list()

    n1 = zip(sum_col3, sum_col4)
    n2 = zip(df['Year'].unique(), n1)
    dictionary = {x[0]: list(x[1]) for x in n2}

    return dictionary
```

The output:

```
{2014: [3250, 1762], 2015: [288, 121], 2016: [159, 61]}
```

Comment: You need `pd.read_csv(fname, sep=',',header=None)` or the first line will be skipped.

Comment: @sys your code is correct :) I didn't want to use pandas, can you tell me what is going wrong with mycode?

Comment: @dawg that is correct  first line is skipped

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import csv 
from itertools import groupby

def conv(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
    
result={}

with open(ur_file) as f_in:
    r=csv.reader(f_in)
    for k,g in groupby(r, key=lambda x:x[0]):
        sl=list(g)
        result[k]=(sum(conv(e[2]) for e in sl), sum(conv(e[3]) for e in sl))

>>> result
{2014: (3355, 1996), 2015: (288, 121), 2016: (159, 61)}
```